# UnityWebRequest for Login

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, webrequest

Has anyone used unitywebrequest to authenticate on an external page, where I am not the administrator? I tried to use the example of the documentation of unity3d but it did not work anyone would have some example

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
public void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Login());
}

private static IEnumerator Login() {
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(
        $"{WebUrl}login", 
        new List<IMultipartFormSection> {
            new MultipartFormDataSection("username", "name"),
            new MultipartFormDataSection("password", "pass"),
        }
    );
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        foreach (var s in www.GetResponseHeaders()) {
            Debug.Log("s=" + s);
        }
    }
}
```